# Solving in $x$ the equation$ \frac{l}{d}=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

Is there a way to solve for $x$ in this equation?
$$\frac{l}{d}=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$$
I was able to approximate it with a Taylor series expansion of $\sin(x)$, but its really bugging me that I can't solve for x exactly.

If you can't solve for $x$ (without any kind of approximation), why?

Comment: What are $\ell$ and $d$? Are they constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply $x=\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}(d/l)$, which doesn't have a more elementary form aside from trivial solutions. Shortly put, the two $x$'s here are on two different 'levels', and it's impossible to put them on the same level since the only ways you can manipulate them with trig functions/identities will always leave at least one $x$ in either a trig or inverse trig function.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=\frac l d$ and consider the equation $$k=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$$ You cannot solve it explicitly but you can have a rather good *approximation* of the solution before starting a numerical method.

For example, using the approximation
 $$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$  (proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician) you would face a quadratic equation
$$\pi\left(\frac{5 \pi }{4}-4   k\right)+(4 k-\pi ) x+x^2=0\implies x=\sqrt{4 k^2+2 \pi  k-\pi ^2}-2 k+\frac{\pi }{2}$$

Starting with estimate as $x_0$, Newton method would converge in a couple of iterations
$$x_{n+1}=k\,\frac{ x_n \cos (x_n)- \sin (x_n)}{k \cos (x_n)-1}$$

Let us try
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 1.1 & 0.74262 & 0.74907 &  0.74899 \\
 1.2 & 1.02288 & 1.02676 &  1.02674 \\
 1.3 & 1.21992 & 1.22150 &  1.22150 \\
 1.4 & 1.37211 & 1.37259 &  1.37259 \\
 1.5 & 1.49572 & 1.49578 &  1.49578 \\
 1.6 & 1.59934 & 1.59935 &  1.59935 \\
 1.7 & 1.68815 & 1.68828 &  1.68828 \\
 1.8 & 1.76555 & 1.76586 &  1.76586 \\
 1.9 & 1.83386 & 1.83438 &  1.83438 \\
 2.0 & 1.89477 & 1.89549 &  1.89549 \\
 2.1 & 1.94956 & 1.95046 &  1.95046 \\
 2.2 & 1.99919 & 2.00024 &  2.00024 \\
 2.3 & 2.04443 & 2.04559 &  2.04559 \\
 2.4 & 2.08587 & 2.08713 &  2.08713 \\
 2.5 & 2.12403 & 2.12535 &  2.12535 \\
 2.6 & 2.15929 & 2.16065 &  2.16065 \\
 2.7 & 2.19201 & 2.19339 &  2.19339 \\
 2.8 & 2.22246 & 2.22385 &  2.22385 \\
 2.9 & 2.25089 & 2.25227 &  2.25227 \\
 3.0 & 2.27751 & 2.27886 &  2.27886
\end{array}
\right)$$

Another simple *approximation* could be obtained after building the $[4,4]$ Padé approximant of the rhs. This would give
$$k=\frac{\frac{5 }{11088}x^4+\frac{13 }{396}x^2+1}{\frac{551 }{166320}x^4-\frac{53   }{396}x^2+1}$$ which is a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

Comment: How long does it take to type such an answer? Impressive!

Comment: Pour ma part, sans avoir une vue en très bon état, je peine à taper de simples formules avec MathJax, alors j'admire!

Comment: Avec *"ἀγεωμέτρητος μηδεὶς εἰσίτω"*, vous me rappelez ma jeunesse puisque je me destinais à Gnouf, lettres pures. Cheers :-)